# Access Denied on news webp objects in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to move towards using webp images for a website so I am creating webp copies of all existing images as follows:

```
my_path = 'bucket-name'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'Some key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'some other key'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(my_path)
s3_path = f'https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/{my_path}/'
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
local_file = '/path to local file/local_image2.jpg'

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='local/media/filer_public_thumbnails/'):
        if  my_bucket_object.key[-4:] == '.jpg' and 'filer_public_thumbnails/' in my_bucket_object.key:
                try:
                    key = my_bucket_object.key

                    image = my_bucket.Object(key)
                    img_data = image.get().get('Body').read()

                    im = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
                    im.save(f'{local_file}.webp', format='webp')

                    s3client.upload_file(f'{local_file}.webp', my_path, f'{key}.webp')
                except Exception as e:
                    self.log(f'Error {e} for {my_bucket_object.key}')

        self.email_log()
```

The webp images are generated fine and when I look at them as they are created locally they are fine.  When I try and look at them in the S3 bucket or retrieve from there I get Access Denied.  I've set public access to ensure it is not that.

What do I need to do?

**EDIT**

I have not blocked public access and I have added a policy as follows to ensure public access:

```
   {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor20",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: How did you "set public access"? Did you also deactivate **Block S3 Public Access**? Please tell us more about how you configured the bucket for public access.

Comment: have you added a policy on Lambda role to allow access to the S3 bucket and objects?

Comment: I'm not using Lambda.  I'm running from server as a one off update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes I made to get this working:

1. I redefined the s3client to include the region and access information

   s3client = boto3.resource(
   service_name='s3',
   region_name=AWS_REGION,
   aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
   aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   )

AND

2. I specified the Bucket it was to be loaded to.

   s3client.Bucket(my_path).upload_file(Filename=f'{local_file}.webp', Key=f'{key}.webp')

Pretty obvious with hindsight!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem because the contentType was passed in incorrectly when uploading the file.
webp should be passed to application/octet-stream, the front-end passed to image/webp. In this case, the contentType returned by the /presignurl interface is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).